# Android, RecyclerView: When to recycle and when not to?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am still fighting with a fluent recycler view that loads images without blocking the ui thread too much.

The problem is in the word "recycle" itself. 
In my app I have a long list with mp3 files that, ofc, all have different names, different artists and different album covers.

However, they all DO use the same layout.

But can I now recycle the view or cant I?

Since loading the album cover right (also cropping it) took the most resources, I have decided to NOT recycle views with an album cover and ONLY recycle those who have no album cover, like so:

```
 private async Task SetContentAsync(PhotoViewHolder vh, int position)
        {
            string SongName = "";
            string ArtistName = "";
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        byte[] data = null;


        try
        {
            reader.SetDataSource(mp3Obj[position].Mp3Uri);
        }
        catch { }


        await Task.Run(() => // cause problems with the reload
        {
            SongName = reader.ExtractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.MetadataKeyTitle);
            ArtistName = reader.ExtractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.MetadataKeyArtist);

            data = reader.GetEmbeddedPicture();

            if (data != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(data, 0, data.Length);
                }
                catch {  }


            }
        });

        ((Activity)ctx).RunOnUiThread(() =>
        {

            vh.SongName.SetTypeface(tf, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
            vh.AristName.SetTypeface(tf, TypefaceStyle.Normal);
            vh.SongName.Text = SongName;
            vh.AristName.Text = ArtistName;

            try
            {
                if (bitmap != null)
                {
                    vh.IsRecyclable = false; // MOST IMPORTANT THING TO DO!
                    ConvertBitmapToBackground(bitmap, vh, false); // Set As Backgorund, blurry and black ( just sets the variable)
                    CutImageIntoForm(bitmap, vh); // Set as the musical note button
                }
                else // because recycler items inherit their shit and if it is altered it just shows views were there shouldnt be any ... 
                {
                    vh.IsRecyclable = true;
                    //  vh.CoverArt.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.btn_musicalnote);
                    //  ConvertBitmapToBackground(bitmap, vh, true); // Set As Backgorund, blurry and black ( just sets the variable)

                }
            }
            catch { }

        });


    }
```

Notice how I say "vh.IsRecyclable = ..." depending on whether there is an album cover or not?

This was the solution with the least amount of lags and works when only a few views include an album cover art. However, when the user has all songs with album covers the recycler view becomes extremely slow.

Another issue I am having is that sometimes, when lag occurs, the views double or even tripple. The still lead to the right file, but they all have the same song name for instance.

So what is best practice? 
When can I recycle a view and when not? 
How can I speed up the recycler view?

Thanks a lot for any answer!

Comment: the RV handles the recycling for you, you shouldn't mess with it. You can likely speed up the processing by caching the image (use a library for image loading and it'll do that for you)

Comment: also for REST calls you can use framework like Volley or Retrofit rather than AsyncTask

Comment: @TimCastelijns Well, I have never messed with it, but this led to the views sometimes 10folding in the RV... since then it gotten better... what image library to you propse?

Comment: no clue. You seem to be using xamarin. Normal logic doesn't apply there

Comment: If you want fluent then you shouldn't be using Xamarin in the first place. Anyways, let the RecyclerView recycle views, it's not up to you to do that. Also, use a proper library for loading images

Comment: @ZUNJAE i tried with picasso, but that only lets me load images from url not from byte array. which library should i use?

Comment: Glide supports loading a byte[]